# Как упростить условие смены направления?

Tags: java

Есть такое условие

```
if (Direction_cam[i] - 180 < 0) { 
    Direction_cam_temp = Direction_cam[i] + 180;
} else {
    Direction_cam_temp = Direction_cam[i] - 180;
}
```

Можно как-то его упростить?

Comment: Точно 180. Надо менять направление движения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно обойтись без явного условия, воспользовавшись тернарным оператором:

```java
Direction_cam_temp = Direction_cam[i] + (Direction_cam[i] < 180 ? 180 : -180);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
degree = 180;

if (Direction_cam[i] >= degree) 
    degree *= -1;

Direction_cam_temp = Direction_cam[i] + degree;
```

---

```
degree = 180;       
Direction_cam_temp = Direction_cam[i] + (Direction_cam[i] < degree ? degree : -degree);
```